# how to reindex python dataframe based on column grouping

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, rows

i am a newbie in python. please assist. I have a huge dataframe consisting of thousands of rows. an example of the df is shown below.

```
        STATE        VOLUME
INDEX           
1       on         10
2       on         15
3       on         10
4       off        20
5       off        30
6       on         15
7       on         20
8       off        10
9       off        30
10      off        10
11      on         20
12      off        25
```

i want to be able to index this data based on the 'state' column such that the first batch of 'on' and 'off' registers as index 1, the next batch of 'on' and 'off' registers as index 2 etc etc... i want to be able to select a group of data if i select rows with index 1.

```
       ID        VOLUME
INDEX           
1       on         10
1       on         15
1       on         10
1       off        20
1       off        30
2       on         15
2       on         20
2       off        10
2       off        30
2       off        10
3       on         20
3       off        25
```

Comment: Is the batch always 5 observations? Could you clarify what do you mean by "the rows don't have similar spacing"? Could you share some code what you have already tried?

Comment: @heilala its not just 5 observations. i only took a portion of the data as it contains thousands of rows that have the 'on' and 'off' batches

Comment: You have 5 times index 1, 5 times index 2... What I meant asking, are the indexes always in batches of 5? Or how do you determine, what observations belong to the same batch?

Comment: Cool 1st question. Welcome to [so] ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this with [`pd.Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) with [`pd.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and take cumsum using [`pd.Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)

```
df.index = (df['STATE'].eq('off').shift() & df['STATE'].eq('on')).cumsum() + 1
df.index.name = 'INDEX'

      STATE  VOLUME
INDEX
1        on      10
1        on      15
1        on      10
1       off      20
1       off      30
2        on      15
2        on      20
2       off      10
2       off      30
2       off      10
3        on      20
3       off      25
```

#### Details

The idea is to find where an `off` is followed by an `on`.

```
# (df['STATE'].eq('off').shift() & df['STATE'].eq('on')).cumsum() + 1

      eq(off).shift  eq(on)  eq(off).shift & eq(on)
INDEX
1               NaN    True                   False
2             False    True                   False
3             False    True                   False
4             False   False                   False
5              True   False                   False
6              True    True                    True
7             False    True                   False
8             False   False                   False
9              True   False                   False
10             True   False                   False
11             True    True                    True
12            False   False                   False
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this with [`pd.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [`pd.Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
df.index=((df.STATE.shift(-1) != df.STATE)&df.STATE.eq('off')).shift(fill_value=0).cumsum()+1
```

Same as this with `np.where`:

```
temp=pd.Series(np.where((df.STATE.shift(-1) != df.STATE)&(df.STATE.eq('off')),1,0))
df.index=temp.shift(1,fill_value=0).cumsum().astype(int).add(1)
```

Output:

```
df
  STATE  VOLUME
1    on      10
1    on      15
1    on      10
1   off      20
1   off      30
2    on      15
2    on      20
2   off      10
2   off      30
2   off      10
3    on      20
3   off      25
```

---

**Explanation**:
With `(df.STATE.shift(-1) != df.STATE)&df.STATE.eq('off')`, you will get a mask with the last value when it changes to 'off':

```
(df.STATE.shift(-1) != df.STATE)&df.STATE.eq('off')

1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5      True
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10     True
11    False
12     True
```

Then you shift it to include that last value, and then you do a `cumsum()` knowing that `True: 1` and `False: 0`:

```
((df.STATE.shift(-1) != df.STATE)&df.STATE.eq('off')).shift(fill_value=0)
1         0
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6      True
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11     True
12    False

((df.STATE.shift(-1) != df.STATE)&df.STATE.eq('off')).shift(fill_value=0).cumsum()
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     1
7     1
8     1
9     1
10    1
11    2
12    2
```

And finally you add 1(`+1`) to the index, to get the desired result.